# Как может выглядеть альтернативное решение?

Tags: java

Задача звучит так:

Перейдите в класс `CycleSwap` и реализуйте его статические методы:

`void cycleSwap(int[] array)`
Сдвигает все элементы в данном массиве вправо на 1 позицию.
В этом случае последний элемент массива становится первым.
Например, 1 3 2 7 4 становится 4 1 3 2 7.

`void cycleSwap(int[] array, int shift)`
Сдвигает все элементы в заданном массиве вправо на shift позиций.
Гарантируется, что значение сдвига неотрицательное и не больше длины массива.
Например, 1 3 2 7 4 со сдвигом 3 становится 2 7 4 1 3.

Для большего интереса при выполнении задания попробуйте не использовать циклы в своем коде (это не обязательно).

Обратите внимание, что входной массив может быть пустым.

Мое решение:

```
class CycleSwap {
    static void cycleSwap(int[] array) {
        if(array.length > 0){
            int lastElement = array[array.length-1];
            for (int i = array.length-1;i>0;i--){
                array[i] = array[i-1];
            }
            array[0] = lastElement;
        }
    }

    static void cycleSwap(int[] array, int shift) {
        if(array.length > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < shift; i++){
                int lastElement = array[array.length-1];
                for(int j = array.length-1;j>0;j--){
                    array[j] = array[j-1];
                }
                array[0] = lastElement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как выглядит альтернативное решение без использования циклов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу несколько путей развития:

1. Рекурсивный подход и реализация `cycleSwap(int[] arr, int shift)` в рамках `cycleSwap(int[] arr)`

```java
public void cycleSwap(int[] arr, int shift) {
  if (shift <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  cycleSwap(cycleSwap(arr), --shift);
}
```

2. Реализация `cycleSwap(int[] arr)` через `System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`

```java
public void cycleSwap(int[] arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  int last = arr[arr.length - 1];
  System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.length - 1);
  arr[0] = last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну навскидку 2 варианта без циклов:

1. Реализуете логику "условно" своих итераторов - попросту ставите указатель, который обозначает начало массива. И когда надо сдвинуть массив вы его не сдвигаете. а сдвигаете указатель на начало. Но тогда при доступе к массиву идете по принципу `(указатель на начало) -> (конец массива) -> (начало массива) -> (указатель на начало)-1`
2. Копируете блоки в новый массив а старый удаляете.